# Having trouble editing and saving a note in my tableview in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, textview

Im having trouble editing and saving a note in my tableview. Ill give you an example, when I add a note to the tableview and then go and edit it it works perfectly. But when I add another note and then try to edit it and save it the note that I first added deletes from the tableview for some reason. I don t get why that happens. Here is the code I use for when I want to edit and save a note.

```
@IBAction func saveAndEditNote(sender: AnyObject) {

    let userDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    let itemList: NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as? NSMutableArray

    let dataSet: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    dataSet.setObject(detailTextView.text, forKey: "text")  

    if ((itemList) != nil) {       
        let newMutableList: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
        newMutableList.addObject(dataSet)
        userDefaults.setObject(newMutableList, forKey: "itemList")

    }

    userDefaults.synchronize()
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false    
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new itemList array, so you will lose any other data that is stored for that key in user defaults, but please, go read about Core Data and do this properly.  Don't use NSUserDefaults for bulk data storage

Comment: Is core data easier to store data? Also can you show me how to fix my code?

Comment: Core Data is a bit more complex but it is a proper object persistence framework so it is easier in the long run.  I can't show you how to fix this code because I don't understand how you are tracking the note being edited index in the array